# RESTFul API complex object creation rollback

Tags: rest, api-design

What is the proper way of handling partial object creation?
Let's say I have a complex object, say class with sections.  So i will have some endpoints like

```
/v1/api/classes
```

and

```
/v1/api/classes/<id>/sections
```

and so i will POST to the first endpoint and then a number of POSTS to the 2nd to create the entire object.  What if one of the section POSTS fails?  I want to rollback the entire class creation.  What's the best way of handling that?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle a larger atomic operation. `POST` as create is very much a convention, but what you put inside the body can be completely up to you.

I feel that's by far the easiest if you want to avoid partial creation and (temporary) invalid state.